# Issue with editing the current command in FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, terminal, freebsd

I have a server running FreeBSD which I ssh to using WSL, if that helps.

On the remote server I have a weird issue that I don't know how to describe, i'll give an example scenario:

Say for example I have a file ~/test.log with thousands of lines with content similar to this:

...
Oct 26 02:04:06 [Info] [93] Writing an info line
Oct 26 02:04:07 [Info] [92] Writing another info line
Oct 26 02:04:08 [Debug] [36] Writing a debug line
Oct 26 02:04:09 [Debug] [92] Writing another debug line
...

Then while I am investigating the file I run commands similar to:

```
> cat ~/test.log
> grep 'Debug' ~/test.log
> cat ~/test.log | awk '{print $4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c
> cat ~/test.log | grep -v 'Info' | awk '{print $4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c
```

after running the third command and realising I need to filter out the Info records, I press the up arrow, press the home key, use the right arrow to navigate to after the pipe, and type " grep -v 'Info'"

In the terminal, I see the following:

```
> cat ~/test.log | grep -v 'Info' $5}' | sort | uniq -c
```

As you can see, the text I have typed has overwritten what was there previously, but only visually, at this point it's actually set to:

```
> cat ~/test.log | grep -v 'Info' awk '{print $4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c
```

If I go ahead and type the " |" the rest of the text reappears on screen. I can also get the rest of the text to appear on screen by pressing the right arrow key, this will correct the display of the character currently under the cursor.

This happens in `sh`, `csh`, `tcsh` and `bash` so it's not related to which shell i am using.

I've tried running `reset` and that just makes everything worse.

I've tried searching for issues of text overwriting itself, and of disappearing text, and issues involving arrow keys, home key, etc. but I can't find the right search term to bring up an answer to this particular issue.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $TERM` on the FreeBSD system? What type of window are you running WSL in, cmd or powershell?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick $TERM returns xterm-256color and I have “Ubuntu” pinned to my task bar. I have no issues when I ssh to my Ubuntu server from it

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If I connect using MobaXterm then it works correctly.

Comment: I can reproduce this. It looks like neither CMD nor Powershell put themselves into insert mode when receiving `CSI 4 h`. Choosing a different terminal type such as `TERM=ansi` works OK, but other terminal types might be more efficient than `ansi`. I will defer to the terminfo experts here for more advice.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks Mark. Is this something that WSL2 will fix? Insert mode is one of the options for the bash window I have open in WSL but guess it doesn’t work in this scenario. I’ll continue with moba for now

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what WSL2 will bring.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I’m having issues installing the latest insider version. Once I get that working I’ll let you know